# What is the reliable method to find most time consuming part of the code?

Tags: python, profiling, performance

Along my source code I try to capture and measure the time release of a segment in Python. How can I measure that segment pass time in a convenient way with good precision?

Comment: I don't want to take credit for this method as my own, but look at this answer by Mike Dunlavey about random pausing that can be used rather than a profiler: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1552

Comment: And [*here is an example in python.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use a **profiler**.

Python's [`cProfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) is included in the standard libary.

For an even more convenient way, use the package [`profilestats`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/profilestats/). Then you can use a decorator to just decorate the functions you want to profile:

```
from profilestats import profile

@profile
def my_function(args, etc):
    pass
```

This will cause a summary like this to be printed on STDOUT:

```
         6 function calls in 0.026 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.026    0.026 some_code.py:3(some_func)
        2    0.019    0.010    0.026    0.013 some_code.py:9(expensive_func)
        2    0.007    0.003    0.007    0.003 {range}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

The much more useful info however is in the `cachegrind.out.profilestats` file generated. You can open this file with a tools that can visualize cachegrind statistics, for example [RunSnakeRun](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/) and get nice, easy (or easier) to read visualizations of your call stack like this:

[image: RunSnakeRun]

**Update**: Both pull requests for [`profilestats`](https://github.com/hannosch/profilestats/pull/1) and [`pyprof2calltree`](https://github.com/pwaller/pyprof2calltree/pull/2) have been merged, so they now support Python 3.x as well.

Comment: What version of Python does `profilestats` support?  There is no indication on the page or even in any of the code that I see...

Comment: You're right, it doesn't indicate supported Python versions on it's PyPi page. It's just a tiny wrapper around `cProfile` ([`profilestats.py`](https://github.com/hannosch/profilestats/blob/master/profilestats.py) is basically all the code), but from a quick glance it's use of `file` instead of `open` means it wont work on Python 3.x as-is. It also depends on `pyprof2calltree`, which is 2.x only. However, both should be easily converted by the `2to3` script, I'm guessing that just no-one has gotten around to making that pull-request yet.

Comment: Python 3.x pull-requests done for [**`pyprof2calltree`**](https://github.com/pwaller/pyprof2calltree/pull/2) and [**`profilestats`**](https://github.com/hannosch/profilestats/pull/1).